# Command running in cmd produces different output than when parsing it in a for-loop

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I am trying to access my network security key using a `for /f` loop. The command I use to get it (in cmd) is as follows:

```bat
netsh wlan show profiles name="NETWORK NAME" key=clear
```

I don't think that is important, but network name includes two words seperated by a space.

I have made several tries on this:

**1.** Try parse it with a simple way:

```bat
for /f "tokens=4" %%A IN ('netsh wlan show profiles name="NETWORK NAME" key=clear ^| findstr /c:"Key content"') do echo %%A
```

This, had no output, so I then tried:

```bat
for /f "tokens=4" %%A IN ('netsh wlan show profiles name="NETWORK NAME" key=clear') do echo %%A
```

which showed me:

```bat
parameters
[[name=]<string>]
of
of
display
data
interface
is
profile
is
listed.
will
set
be
are
preference
1"
2"
3"
```

which with `delims=` options is:

```bat
One or more parameters for the command are not correct or missing.
Usage: show profiles [[name=]<string>] [interface=<string>] [key=<string>]
Parameters:
    Tag             Value
    name          - Name of the profile to display.
    interface     - Name of the interface which has this profile configured.
    key           - To display the key in plain text, set key=clear.
Remarks:
    Shows the profile data or lists the profiles on the system.
    Parameter name and interface are both optional.
    If profile name is given then the content of the profile will be
    displayed. Otherwise only profile name and description will be listed.
    If interface name is given, only the specified profile on the given
    interface will be listed. Otherwise, all profiles with the given name
    on the system will be listed.
    If key is set to "clear" and the caller is local administrator,
    the key will be shown in plain text.
    Group Policy Profiles are read only. User Profiles are readable and
    writeable, and the preference order can be changed.
Examples:
    show profiles name="profile 1" interface="Wireless Network Connection"
    show profiles name="profile 2"
    show profiles name="profile 3" key=clear
    show profiles
```

**2.** Using `usebackq`:

```bat
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A IN (`netsh wlan show profiles name="NETWORK NAME" key=clear`) do echo %%A
```

Same output as above...

**3.** Set network name as a variable quoted:

```bat
set network="NETWORK NAME"
for /f "delims=" %%A IN ('netsh wlan show profiles name=%network% key=clear') do echo %%A
```

Same output as above even using `usebackq`.

**4.** Set network name as a variable unquoted:

```bat
set network=NETWORK NAME
for /f "delims=" %%A IN ('netsh wlan show profiles name="%network%" key=clear') do echo %%A
```

Same output as above, even with `usebackq`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to escape some special chars. `=` is one of them:

```
for /f "delims=" %%A IN ('netsh wlan show profiles name^="NETWORK NAME" key^=clear') do echo %%A
```

Other chars that have to be escaped are: `<>|&,)`

Comment: *Poison character* is not really correct. It would be better to write *characters interpreted as argument separators* by Windows command processor.

Comment: @Mofi ...and poisonous here. `:)`. I changed my wording. (if it were "argument separators", spaces would have to be escaped too)

Comment: @Stephan Spaces must not be escaped because of `cmd.exe` replaces the characters comma `,`, semicolon `;`, equal sign `=` and no-break space (OEM encoded with code value 255 decimal) being interpreted as argument separators by a normal space character on not being escaped with caret `^` or being inside a double quoted argument string before executing the command __FOR__. This can be seen on running a batch file with the command line ``for /F %%I in ('pause A!BC#D$E+F,G-H.I/J:K;L=M?N@O[P]Q`R{S}T~U V') do echo %%I`` in a cmd window with output ``A!BC#D$E+F G-H.I/J:K L M?N@O[P]Q`R{S}T~U V``.